# copy file based on content - command prompt

Tags: windows, copy, command, prompt

I got a folder with bunch of files in it. each file name has unique date ex: 20140101. each file has data of one product.. ex: 20140101 has data for product "oranges" file 20140102 has data of product "apple" .. I need to create a script which will check the content of file and if match found, copy the file to different directory.

Example:

Find "Oranges" in 
C:\Data\

found 2 files .. 20131229 and 20140101

copy files to c:\oranges\

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=c:\data\*.*"
    set "target=c:\"
    set "classes=orange apple"

for %%c in (%classes%) do (
    if not exist "%target%%%c\" md "%target%%%c\"
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('findstr /m /l /c:"%%c" "%source%"') do (
        copy "%%~ff" "%target%%%c\"
    )
)
```

For each of the indicated classes, create target directory if it does not exist, and for each file with the indicated content, move it to the adecuated directory (not tested, adapt as needed)

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. But I have different problem now. Few files has details about both Oranges and Apple. Is there is any way while searching if we find more than one entry per file, script will copy respective line and paste it in a file created in destination folder as source filename?

Comment: @user3346080, replace `copy` line with `findstr /l /c:"%%c" "%%~ff" > "%target%%%c\%%~nxf"`